# How model relationships works with blades?

Tags: laravel

I have a model 'applicants' and it has a 'belongsTo' relationship with 'BloodGroup' model.

Here is the index function from ApplicantController:

```php
    public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        // $user = User::find(1);
        $applicants = $user->applicants->where('visible', 1);

        foreach ($applicants as $applicant) {
            $applicant->bloodGroup;
            $applicant->fiqa;
            $applicant->gender;
        }
        // return response()->json($applicants);
        return view('applicants.index', ['applicants' => $applicants]);
    }
```

Here is the response that I get from the API:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": 4,
        "blood_group_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-04-22 13:24:16",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-26 10:21:41",
        "blood_group": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "A+",
            "visible": 1,
            "created_at": "2019-04-22 08:21:19",
            "updated_at": "2019-04-22 08:21:19"
        }
    }
}
```

But when I pass data to the view. It generates an error in the following lines:

```php
    <div class="row mx-4">
       <div class="col-06 pr-3">
          <p class="h5">Name:</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-06">
          <p><?php echo e($applicant->blood_group->name); ?></p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

BloodGroup Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BloodGroup extends Model
{
    public function applicants()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Applicant');
    }
}
```

BloodGroup relationship in Applicants table:

```
public function bloodGroup()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\BloodGroup');
}
```

Can you please point out what I'm doing wrong and how this should be done.

Comment: It seems there are some `$applicant` for which there is no `blood_group` or there are some `blood_group` with no name.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I check and all the applicants have some blood group id and all the blood groups have names.

Comment: In your foreach loop you are doing nothing, can you explain me the purpose of this loop?

Comment: I'm dynamically creating a table to show each applicants information in one row.

Comment: What changes it is making to `$applicants`?

Comment: no changes. just iterating through its items.

Comment: So if there is no purpose, that is unnecessarily taking resources, so you should avoid it, then change `$user->applicants->where('visible', 1)` to `$user->applicants->where('visible', 1)->get()` and tell me what you are getting for `dd($applicants)` .

Comment: Can you post the `bloodGroup` relationship definition and the blade file?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu `->get()` is not necessary since `$users->applicants` is a collection and not a query builder. Although he could replace it with `$users->applicants()->where('visible', 1)->get()` for (slightly) better performance.

Comment: @Thomas I edited the question and added the BloodGroup Model.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for the `bloodGroup` relationship  in the `Applicant` model. Forgot to mention that at first.

Comment: @Thomas check the new edit.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I tried with the get() and got the same error. And when I did dd($applicants), I got the same result as before.

Comment: Also you may consider using @php tag if you want to use echo else you may like to use `{{ $applicant->blood_group->name }}` instead.

Comment: I would also like to see if you are getting error on `$applicant->blood_group` as you are getting error on `$boodgroup->name` part.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu No, I'm not getting any error on `$applicant->blood_group`

Comment: @user8114666 can you try my answer, just I have posted and let me know the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your relationship suggests

```
public function bloodGroup()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\BloodGroup');
}
```

for a particular applicant, `$applicant = Applicant::find(1);`, you will be able to get bloodGroup like `$applicant->bloodGroup`, now you should be able to get the name with `$applicant->bloodGroup->name`.

Your code should be

```
 public function index()
  {
     $user = Auth::user();
     $applicants = $user->applicants()->where('visible', 1)->get();
     return view('applicants.index', ['applicants' => $applicants]);
  }
```

In your view

```
@foreach ( $applicants as $applicant )
    {{ $applicant->bloodGroup->name }}
@endforeach
```

@swonder's concern

```
>>> App\User::find(1)->roles->where('role_id', '<', 1)
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3178
     all: [
       App\models\Role {#3166
         id: 1,
         name: "super-admin",
         display_name: "Super Admin",
         description: "This will be one permission, that can not be assigned or
modified.",
         created_at: "2019-01-11 19:06:23",
         updated_at: "2019-01-11 19:06:23",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3141
           user_id: 1,
           role_id: 1,
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

yes @swonder is correct, you should use

```
$user->applicants()->where('visible', 1)->get();
```

and not `$user->applicants->where('visible', 1)` instead you may try collection where with `all()` or `get()`, but you may not prefer that after looking into below observation

```
>>> App\User::find(1)->roles->where('role_id', '=', 1)
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3160
     all: [],
   }
>>> App\User::find(1)->roles->whereStrict('role_id', '=', 1)
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3163
     all: [],
   }
>>> App\User::find(1)->roles->whereStrict('role_id', '<', 1)
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3169
     all: [],
   }
>>> App\User::find(1)->roles->whereStrict('role_id', '>', 1)->all()
=> []
>>> App\User::find(1)->roles->whereStrict('role_id', '>', 1)->all()
>>> App\User::find(1)->roles->whereStrict('role_id', '=', 1)->all()
=> []
>>> App\User::find(1)->roles->whereStrict('role_id', '>', 1)->all()
=> []
```

Comment: this worked for me, but why? Because this is what I'm getting when calling the same API: https://pastebin.com/yxjdVpZ6

Comment: @swonder check in your tinker, without checking do not put a question, it is working perfectly I have checked and the SO has confirmed.

Comment: @user8114666 there is no wrong with it, I have checked in tinker, either you use `$user->applicants->where('visible', 1);` or `$user->applicants()->where('visible', 1)->get();`

Comment: [Please read the documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

Comment: @swonder `$user->posts()->where('active', 1)->get();` is different from `$user->posts->where('active', 1)->get();` and `posts` is different from `posts()` adding a perfect example for `$user->roles` wait.

Comment: That tinker is even wrong, you put where role_id is less than 1, yet it returned a role_id of 1?

Comment: @swonder then check https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-where as `$user->posts` is a collection.

Comment: @swonder I have edited my answer with my observation, I hope this will be helpful to everyone now.

Comment: @swonder you are free to edit it, if you think there is something I have missed or post a separate answer.

Comment: @user8114666 please look into my answer again, I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error that it says?

`return view('applicants.index', ['applicants' => $applicants]);`

You are passing `applicants` to the view but you use `$applicant` in it. Are you looping over `$applicants`? If no that's the error.

Comment: yes I'm looping through the applicants using @foreach. And the error is 
"Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

Comment: Ok. Can you debug your `$applicants` in your view? Use `dd($applicants);`

Comment: I did and everything is as expected and should be working fine.

Comment: Replace `<?php echo e($applicant->blood_group->name); ?>` with `{{ $applicant->blood_group->name }}`

Comment: Actually, I'm using exactly this. I just showed you the code that was returned by laravel on the browser.

Comment: Try to use the array syntax `{{ $applicant->blood_group['name'] }}`

Comment: I also tried this, with this laravel does not throw any error but this returns null.

Comment: So make a `dd($applicants)` in your blade template and put the results in the post to see if you are retrieving the data ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding issue with your code, since you're running a query but not actually asking anything out of it here:

`$applicants = $user->applicants()->where('visible', 1);`

This will need to be come:

`$applicants = $user->applicants()->where('visible', 1)->get();`

Since you're calling them anyway, perhaps try eager loading the relationships with:

`$applicants = $user->applicants()->with('blood_group')->where('visible', 1)->get();`

Resulting in your index method to look like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $applicants = $user->applicants()->with('blood_group')->where('visible', 1)->get();

    return view('applicants.index', ['applicants' => $applicants]);
}
```

Then you can access `$applicants` in your blade file like so:

```
@foreach($applicants as $applicant)
<div class="row mx-4">
   <div class="col-06 pr-3">
      <p class="h5">Name:</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-06">
      <p>{{$applicant->blood_group->name}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `$user->applicants->where('visible', 1)->get();` this throws error but work as before if put like this: `$user->applicants()->where('visible', 1)->get();` and `'$user->applicants->with('blood_group')->where('visible', 1)->get();` this also did not work and should not work because blood_group has a 'hasMany' relationship with the applicant model not he other way around.

Comment: Since you're running queries on $user->applicants through the relationship, you will have to use the method like so `$user->applicants()`, I've edited that in as I missed it when copying your code. `$user->applicants()->with('blood_group')` does work and will work since you're calling EACH applicant with their respective blood group via a belongsTo method. Please read the documentation.